# Binding to user control's collection property items in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have created a user control with collection property:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
    MyListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyList",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Test>),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Test>())
        );

    public ObservableCollection<Test> MyList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Test>)base.GetValue(MyListProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(MyListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty
    BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "B",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public string B
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(BProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(BProperty, value); }
    }
```

The Test class is:

```
public class Test : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
    AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "A",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Test),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public string A 
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(AProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(AProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then, i'm trying to use my control for binding:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="def"/>
    <my:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1" B="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Text}">
        <my:UserControl1.MyList>
            <my:Test A="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Text}"></my:Test>
            <my:Test A="100"></my:Test>
        </my:UserControl1.MyList>
    </my:UserControl1>
```

The first binding (with B property of User Control) works correctly. The problem is with second binding (with A property of Test which is MyList element). When debugging i have two items in MyList but the A property of the first one is null. Please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that the Binding to ElementName=tb1 can not be resolved, even it will never be evaluated. A Binding to an ElementName is resolved for DependencyObjects which are in the visual or logical Tree of a WPF Application. Adding items to your ObservableCollection (MyList) only means adding the items to the Collection, but not into the Visual Tree.

**Edit**:
Here is the approach discussed in the comments:

In your Window/Page:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Declare the ViewModel as Resource -->
    <my:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel">
        <my:ViewModel.MyList>
            <my:Test A="Hello sweet" />
            <my:Test A="ViewModel" />
        </my:ViewModel.MyList>
    </my:ViewModel>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- Assign Ressource as DataContext -->
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">

    <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="def"/>

    <!-- Reference your list within the ViewModel -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Bind your property  -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=A}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And the implementation of ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.MyList = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Test> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, class Test no longer needs to implement a DependencyObject. Simple get/set Properties are okay.

Comment: Ok, so how to make it work like in ListBox control? -> binding to ListBoxItem works correctly.

Comment: add a `ListBox` to your XAML for your `UserControl1`. Bind the `ItemsSource` of the ListBox to your list `ItemsSource={Binding Path=MyList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:UserControl1}}`. Set the ItemTemplate to a DataTemplate, which contains a TextBlock e.g., which Binds to A `Text={Binding Path=A}`. This should do what you intend.

Comment: Could you post an example code because I don't get it and I'm not sure if you understood what I need. I want to populate MyList with items (Test objects) from xaml, like it is done in ListBox:             <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Text}"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Text}"/>
            </ListBox.Items>

Comment: Okay I could do this, but in fact I need some more information on what you are actually going to achieve. How do you want to use your MyList? What you did already is pretty much uncommon for WPF coding. Perhaps I can show you a better way, if I know the use case in detail.

Comment: P.S: you asked how it works for ListBoxes: A ListBox is an ItemsControl. The ItemsContainer of a ListBox is a ListBoxItem, a simple ContentControl, which holds an ContentPresenter, that visualizes the actual data by the ItemTemplate. For each item which is added to the ListBox.Items collection, a container is generated (ListBoxItem), and then the data gets visualized. Adding ListBoxItems with Content directly from XAML is also possible. Internally, by default in the Template of a ListBox, the ItemContainers are added to a VirtualizingStackPanel which then is the direct parent in visual tree

Comment: If you want the same behavior, inherit from ItemsControl and override the container generation methods or add your MyList as ItemsSource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266735/creating-custom-itemscontrol

Comment: There is a ListBox control. When we declare it, in xaml file, we can initialize it by specifying any number of <ListBoxItem> elements. Each property (Content, IsEnabled) of single ListBoxItem element we can bind with something (for example for one ListBoxItem we can bind Content to Text property of TextBox and for another one we can bind IsEnabled to IsChecked property of CheckBox). What I want to do is user control which will enable me to create similar markup in xaml to initialize a Collection of Custom Type just like collection of ListBoxItem is initialized in ListBox.

Comment: Okay I understood, but the root cause of the problem stays the same as in my answer. You will be never able to bind these items if they are not in the logical or visual tree of you application, since the Binding will not find a parent where it can resolve the ElementName you are looking for. Have a look at the output: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'Test' (HashCode=58400548); target property is 'A' (type 'String')`

Comment: if you want to initialize the collection in xaml, you will have to put the items into visual tree. I can show it if you want to, but it really makes no sense to me. A better way would be to use the MVVM Pattern, with a ViewModel which encapsulates your MyList.

Comment: Probabely you are right :). How did you get that output? My code is compiling without any errors and there are also no errors at runtime. Creating ViewModel will lead to initializing MyList collection from code yes?

Comment: That is a basic WPF problem ;) Binding Errors do not raise compile/runtime Exceptions unless you enforce this. You see the error Message during runtime in the Output Debug window of VisualStudio (Debug -> Windows -> Output). You dont essentialy have to do this in code. You can instantiate every class from XAML Markup. One way would be to do this in your Resources section. I will show it in another answer in a few secs.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please mark as answer if you appreciate my help ;)