# XAML Binding to custom control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

I have built a custom control and want to know how to properly bind in XAML to a property of an item in an Observable collection in the custom control. The custom control property looks like this.

```
Public Property MyPoints As ObservableDependencyObjectCollection(Of MyPoint)
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(MyPointsProperty), ObservableDependencyObjectCollection(Of MyPoint))
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableDependencyObjectCollection(Of MyPoint))
        SetValue(MyPointsProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

MyPoint contains two properties X and Y

Full XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfDependencyPropertyVB">

<Grid>
    <my:CustomControl1   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,212,0,0" x:Name="CustomControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="67">
        <my:CustomControl1.MyPoints>
            <my:MyPoint X="100" Y="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1}" />
        </my:CustomControl1.MyPoints>
    </my:CustomControl1>
    <Slider Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,174,0,0" Name="Slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1}" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,145,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" />
</Grid>
```

enter code here

In My XAML the set up looks like this:

```
<my:CustomControl1 x:Name="CustomControl11" >
    <my:CustomControl1.MyPoints>
        <my:MyPoint X="100" Y="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1}" />
    </my:CustomControl1.MyPoints>
</my:CustomControl1>
```

If I set a break point in my control I can see that X=100 but i don't see that Y is updated when the Slider Value changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the Visual Studio output window. There might be binding errors shown there.

Comment: That is correct but i'm still not shure how to properly bind. the error I get "System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Value; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyPoint' (HashCode=16014678); target property is 'Y' (type 'Double')"

Comment: Post your full XAML (containing the Slider etc).

Comment: Full XAML added above  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Which item in the collection are you trying to bind to, the first or the hundredth?  Is there an item in the collection?

Comment: My:MyPoint is the first item in the collection. MyPoint item has two properties X which is set to  value of 100 and Y which is the property I want to bind to and have its value equal the value of Slider1.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528286/binding-to-user-controls-collection-property-items-in-xaml

Comment: Why do you need an ObservableCollection then?  Can't you have an X and Y dependency property?

Comment: @Phil I think he wants to add more than one Point to his CustomControl1.

Comment: @user2254705   
You could add x:Name="someName" to your MyPoint object and in the constructor of your Window you do this: `NameScope.SetNameScope(someName, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));`. Now your Binding could work (it worked where I had a problem similar to this). ;)

Comment: Hi Florian, Would this work for multiple MyPoint Items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to add a dependency property `ThePoint` to `CustomControl1` and then bind the slider value to `ThePoint.Y`.  I'm assuming that MyPoint derives from DependencyObject and that X and Y are dependency properties.

```
<my:CustomControl1 x:Name="theControl" />

<Slider Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding ElementName=theControl, 
        Path=ThePoint.Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

You could then add PropertyChangedCallback handlers as required to add items to the collection (if that's what's required).

Alternatively you can bind to an item in the collection:

```
<local:MyCustomControl x:Name="theControl" />

<Slider Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding ElementName=theControl, 
        Path=MyPoints[0].Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Hello Phil I need to be able to add multiple items to the collection and bind to each items Y property. MyPoint is only one item in the collection. If i understand your solution correctly my control would only have the ability to bind the Y property for one item.

Comment: Hello Phil- That works great! Do you know how I woul be able to set the binding at my custom control insted of at the Slider? something similar to what I posted.

Comment: I don't see how to do it the other way around.  You're only able to put MyPoints[n] in the binding (afaik).